# how to launch application automatically on Scheduled Time in react native even when app is closed?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i have application in react native and i want to open App at 12 PM automatically but dont know how to do it, any solutions?

i am using following libraries,
react-native-background-task
react-native-push-notifications

Comment: Jigar Prajapati, Have you found any solutions for this requirement. I too have same requirement. Could you please post the answer if you found the solution. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: no i am still looking for the solution.

Comment: Jigar Prajapati if you found any solution please post here it will helpful to me and many. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no i still didn't find any solution.